# How to add a rangeInput using rails simple_form?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

Is it possible to add a [rangeInput](http://jquerytools.org/documentation/rangeinput/) or anything similar, using rails simple form gem?

Thanks!

Comment: I know this. But, simple_form has it?

Comment: if you can embed jQuery than it is possible

Comment: HTML5 has the type range for the input element.  You could use with simple_form like this:
 ```<%= f.input :percentage, as: :range,
        html_input: {
        type: 'range',
        min: 0,
        max: 100} %>```